# Static constructor called twice

Tags: c#, arrays, list, constructor, static

Previously I've had a `static TopUp()` method what I wanted to substitute with the Baseclass's static constructor, because it's "performed once only" as the msdn states.
[msdn: Static Constuctor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx)
Any solution for keep the derived classes' initialization in the constructor and perform it only once?

```
class BaseClass<T>
{
    static BaseClass()
    {
        for (byte i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            var temp = new Junction<byte>[2] { new Level2<byte>(), new OtherLevel2<byte>() };
            Program.myList.Add(temp);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("static BaseClass()");
    }
}

abstract class Junction<T> : BaseClass<T> { }

sealed class Level2<T> : Junction<T> { }

sealed class OtherLevel2<T> : Junction<T> { }

class Program
{
    internal static List<Junction<byte>[]> myList = new List<Junction<byte>[]>();
    static Program()
    {
        BaseClass<object> callTheStaticMethod = new BaseClass<object>();
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("myList.Count = " + myList.Count);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

Output:  
static BaseClass()  
static BaseClass()  
myList.Count = 4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your static construction *is* called only once. Once per type, that is.

Each time you use your `BaseClass<T>` with a different type parameter, that's a completely different type. So, `Junction<byte>`, which inherits `BaseClass<byte>`, is a different type from `BaseClass<object>`. The static constructor for `BaseClass<byte>` is called, as well as the static constructor for `BaseClass<object>`.

It's not really clear from your question what it is you're actually trying to achieve. I will say, that the use of `Junction<byte>` in the static constructor strongly suggests that your class is not really generic at all. Any other use of `BaseClass<T>` is necessarily still dependent on `Junction<byte>`, and thus `BaseClass<byte>`. And this probably negates whatever benefit you thought you were going to get by making the class generic.

You can force the static constructor to execute only once by moving it to a non-generic base class inherited by `BaseClass<T>`. E.g.:

```
class BaseClass { /* static constructor here */ }
class BaseClass<T> : BaseClass { /* other stuff */ }
```

But given the lack of generic-ness in the class to start with, it's not clear that this will really help much. There seems to be a broader design flaw here that should be addressed.

Comment: I cleared all of the unnecessary code that's why seems generic-ness. Just learning and try to play around with the generics. I didn't think about that two different parameter create two different type, but seems obvious now. Thank you. It works.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you have the static initializer in a *typed* base class.  The issue is that `BaseClass<string>` and `BaseClass<int>` are considered two different types.  The actual classes are generated at compile time, and so the compiler duplicates the static initializer for each variation.

If you change the last line in the static initializer to include the name of the type you'll be able to get a better idea of this issue.

In .Net 4.6 you can do this:

```
Console.WriteLine($"static BaseClass<{nameof(T)}>()");
```

In .Net 4.0 or later you can do this:

```
string typeName = typeof(T).FullName;
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("static BaseClass<{0}>()", typeName));
```

To resolve your issue, do your static initialization in a standard class that does not have a type parameter.  In this case, you can simply remove the `<T>` type parameter from the BaseClass.  Example:

```
class BaseClass
{
    static BaseClass()
    {
        for (byte i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            var temp = new Junction<byte>[2] { new Level2<byte>(), new OtherLevel2<byte>() };
            Program.myList.Add(temp);
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"static BaseClass<{nameof(T)}>()");
    }
}

abstract class Junction<T> : BaseClass { }

sealed class Level2<T> : Junction<T> { }

sealed class OtherLevel2<T> : Junction<T> { }
```

Comment: I think you have the right idea, but your terminology ("typed" vs "class that does not have a type") is non-standard and very unclear for talking about generics.

Comment: I'm not seeing anywhere I'm referring to a class that does not have a type.  I'm having a hard time parsing what you mean in your comment.

Comment: That was a direct quote from your last paragraph.

Comment: OK, I see it now.  Cleaning up the language.

Comment: _"The actual classes are generated at compile time, and so the compiler duplicates the static initializer for each variation"_ -- this is not strictly true. Consider, e.g. `List<T>` in the framework. The compiled framework has the single generic type, with no concrete (constructed) types. Also, for types `T` where `T` is a reference type, the static initializer is "duplicated" only conceptually; there is only ever really one copy of the method's code for all `T` (of course, `byte` is a value type, so you do get a copy of the entire generic type for that, specific to `byte`)

Comment: @PeterDuniho, there are two stages.  `List<T>` is a generic template that has all the instructions to generate the final type, but when you have code that specifies that type parameter and instantiate an instance you'll have the final typed classes.  The bottom line is that you have a new call to the static initializer for each time you provide a type parameter to the generic.

Comment: _"The bottom line is that you have a new call to the static initializer for each time you provide a type parameter to the generic"_ -- that's true. But the way you word your explanation, it sounds like you are saying that the code in the static constructor (and indeed, all the code for the type) is duplicated for each different `T`. That's not correct, when `T` is a reference type.